# In photoshop 7, how do I change the font layer background color without rasterizing the layer?

Tags: software, photoshop

In photoshop 7, how do I change the font layer background color without rasterizing the layer?

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably off-topic for photo.se?

Comment: Hello Wiskin, and welcome to Photo.SE. I do apologize having to do this on your first question, however general Photoshop questions are off topic here. We are a photography related forum, and while we do answer questions involving Photoshop, they must be primarily related to photographic editing. I am closing this question as off-topic, however I hope that you will stick around, and ask any photography related questions you may have in the future.

Comment: I think this question was on the fringe, I answered it because I found it relevant in the context of creating watermarks on a photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough one, Photoshop 7 is almost 8 years old. I've to be honest, I'm not sure what you mean by font layer *background* color (UPDATE: now I know). A font layer is transparent by default, and the only color you can change is the color of the text/font itself (but I assume you know how to do that).

Layer effects were introduced in PS6 if I recall, but that's not going to help either because they are only affecting the pixels in the layer (here, the text).

In later PS versions you can transform a layer into a smart object, and apply the Invert filter to that smart layer; e.g. a black text on white would become a white text on a black background. Unfortunately, I tried and while you can transform a text layer into as mart object, you can't apply an Invert filter on it. An Invert Adjustment Layer with a layer mask is not working either. The whole issue here is that I don't think PS gives you access to the bounding box of a text layer. If you Control+Click on the layer, it will select the outline of the text, not its bounding box.

Comment: I think he means he wants a solid colour behind the text, which you can do in Illustrator and InDesign but not any version of Photoshop as far as I know...

Comment: Oh I see now, I was confused because I didn't get what would be the physical extent of that "background". I assume that is the bounding box of the text.

Answer (score 0):

The text tool is not something I use that often in Photoshop so I may be wrong, but I always thought that the background of a text layer in Photoshop is always transparent - thus it's impossible to change it without rasterizing.

I know that in Adobe InDesign you can set the text background to a specific colour, as I use that quite often for effect:

[image]

Assuming the above is the type of effect you're going for then I'm afraid I don't think it's possible.